# Stop and Resume Jquery Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have used following code:

```
$('#counter').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    jQuery({ 
        Counter: 0 
    }).animate({ 
        Counter: $this.text() 
    }, {
        duration:30000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function () {
            $this.text(Math.ceil(30 - this.Counter));
        },
        complete: function() {
            $("#count_block").css("display","inline-block");
            $this.text(0);
        }
    });
});
```

I have a `Pause` and `Resume` button on my webpage. How can I pause or resume the animation that I started using above code?

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hasmukhmistry/sztkso3y/)

Comment: try to add the fiddle....with minimum possible code

Comment: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/hasmukhmistry/sztkso3y/

Comment: I have edit my answer, please try it.

Comment: @HasmukhMistry: http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/d0bsce1p/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use jQuery clearQueue:

You can find more details: http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/

**UPDATE**

Ok try this: it's working fine. The animation auto update the duration.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    myDiv = $( "#counter" );
 totalCount = parseInt(myDiv.text());
 animDuration = 30000;
 counter();
  
 $( "#start" ).click(function() {
  counter();
 });
   
 $( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  animDuration = parseInt(myDiv.text()) * 1000;
  myDiv.clearQueue();
  myDiv.stop();
 });
});

function counter(){
    $('#counter').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        jQuery(this).animate({ Counter: totalCount}, {
            duration:animDuration,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function () {
                $this.text(Math.ceil(30 - this.Counter));
            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#count_block").css("display","inline-block");
                    $this.text(0);
            }
        });
    });   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter" style="float:left;background:#13AD2A;color:#fff;font-size:32px;padding:30px;display:inline-block;width:40px;text-align:center">
    30
</div>

<div id="count_block" style="display:none;float:left;background:#13AD2A;color:#fff;padding: 13px 10px;margin: 8px 0px 8px 10px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 15px;">
    Counter Completed
</div> 
 
<div id="counter1" style="float:left;background:#13AD2A;color:#fff;padding:39px;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#fff;" id="stop">Pause</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#fff;" id="start">Play</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried clear queue , and stopped another animation on the same page.. But using clearqueue i am not able to stop this animation that i mentioned... Can you look for the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hasmukhmistry/sztkso3y/ and try to find out a way how to stop this...Many thanks

Comment: It works like a champ, Brilliant ... I tried using many plugins to do this but all fails against the exact requirement , And i did this custom code but stucked in this.. you helped me a lot ..

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly what i want ...

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  myDiv = $( "#counter" );
  totalCount = parseInt(myDiv.text());
  animDuration = 30000;
  counter();
  
  $( "#start" ).click(function() {
   counter();
  });
   
  $( "#stop" ).click(function() {
   animDuration = parseInt(myDiv.text()) * 1000;
   myDiv.clearQueue();
   myDiv.stop();
  });
 });
 function counter(){
  $('#counter').each(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   jQuery(this).animate({ Counter: totalCount}, {
    duration:animDuration,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function () {
     $this.text(Math.ceil(30 - this.Counter));
    },
    complete: function() {
     $("#count_block").css("display","inline-block");
     $this.text(0);
    }
   });
  });   
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter" style="float:left;background:#13AD2A;color:#fff;font-size:32px;padding:30px;display:inline-block;width:40px;text-align:center">
    30
</div>

<div id="count_block" style="display:none;float:left;background:#13AD2A;color:#fff;padding: 13px 10px;margin: 8px 0px 8px 10px;font-size: 14px;line-height: 15px;">
    Counter Completed
</div> 
 
 <div id="counter1" style="float:left;background:#13AD2A;color:#fff;padding:39px;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#fff;" id="stop">Pause</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="color:#fff;" id="start">Play</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's P. Frank answer.